# Sanitize all except number, forward slash and $?

Tags: php

I have an entry form for 'price', and want something like:

> $250 full price /$230 early booking

To be sanitized within the database to:

```
250/230
```

Or

```
$250/$230
```

Is it possible to do either in PHP?

I've tried:

```
$formdata = ( isset( $_POST['price-entry'] ) ? sanitize_html_class( $_POST['price-entry'] ) : '' );
```

But this strips everything except letters and digits.

Comment: you can simply do: `preg_replace("/[^\d\/]+/", "", $text);`

Comment: @Akam almost! `preg_replace("/[^\/\d]+/", "", $text);` or `preg_replace("/[^$\/\d]+/", "", $text);`

Comment: Thanks, but will preg_replace clean up the database entry or just the output? I need the database entry to be clean.

Comment: It will remove all values from a $variable that is not a digit, forward slash (/) or dollar sign ($). What you do with the value (like save it in the database) is up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
  $price = '$250 full price /$230 early booking';
  echo get_clean_price($price);

  function get_clean_price($price) {
    return preg_replace("/[^\d\/]+/", "", $price);
  }
```